# How can I check whether every second value from a dictionary is in a specific range?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary which reads in from a file called peaks_ee.xpk.

sample from peaks_ee.xpk:

```
label dataset sw sf
1H 1H_2
NOESY_F1eF2e.nv
4807.69238281 4803.07373047
600.402832031 600.402832031
1H.L 1H.P 1H.W 1H.B 1H.E 1H.J 1H.U 1H_2.L 1H_2.P 1H_2.W 1H_2.B 1H_2.E 1H_2.J 1H_2.U vol int stat comment flag0 flag8 flag9
0 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
1 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
2 {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
3 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
4 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H1'} 5.90291 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
5 {2.H1'} 5.90291 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
6 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
7 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
8 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
9 {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
10 {3.H6} 7.53261 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {4.H1'} 5.74125 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
11 {4.H1'} 5.74125 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {3.H6} 7.53261 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
12 {3.H1'} 5.54935 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {4.H8} 7.49932 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
13 {4.H8} 7.49932 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {3.H1'} 5.54935 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
14 {3.H6} 7.53261 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {3.H1'} 5.54935 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
15 {3.H1'} 5.54935 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {3.H6} 7.53261 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
16 {3.H6} 7.53261 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H1'} 5.90291 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
17 {3.H6} 7.53261 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
18 {2.H1'} 5.90291 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {3.H6} 7.53261 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
19 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {3.H6} 7.53261 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
20 {4.H8} 7.49932 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {4.H1'} 5.74125 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
21 {4.H1'} 5.74125 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {4.H8} 7.49932 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
22 {4.H8} 7.49932 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {3.H1'} 5.54935 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
23 {4.H8} 7.49932 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {3.H6} 7.53261 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
24 {3.H1'} 5.54935 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {4.H8} 7.49932 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0`
```

In line 0 of peaks_ee.xpk for example, the atom name is 1.H1' and it's chemical shift is 5.82020. In the same line, in the 8th column, there is another atom name, 2.H8 and it's chemical shift is 7.61004. Basically I want to check if the first chemical shift in the row (5.82020) is in a certain range and if the second chemical shift (7.49932) is in another range. If it is, then write out the atom names (1.H1' and 2.H8) to a file called tclust.txt

This is the code so far, I posted another question before and @wwii helped me with this code.

```
pattern = '''{(\d\.H\d'?)}\s(\d\.\d+)\s'''
rex = re.compile(pattern)

j = 0;
contents_atom = []
atom_lines=[]

result = {}
with open("peaks_ee.xpk","r") as atom_name:
    for line in atom_name:
        for match in rex.finditer(line):
            name, shift = match.groups()
            if name not in result:
                result[name] = float(shift)
                print (name,shift)
                    if filename == 'ee_pinkH1.xpk':
                        if result[name]<=8.5
                            float_str = re.findall("\d\.\H\d'?",name)
                            if (len(float_str))>1:
                                j=j+1
                                value1 = ('Atom ' + str(j) + ' ' + str(float_str[0])+ ' ' + str(float_str[1])+ '\n')
                                atom_lines.insert(-1,value1)

tclust_atom = open("tclust.txt","a")
for value1 in atom_lines:
    tclust_atom.write(value1)
tclust_atom.close()
```

This is a picture of a list of the atom names and their chemical shifts which was printed out from the line `print (names,shift)`

[atom names and chemical shifts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1UR0.png)

From that picture, the first two lines are:

"1.H1'","5.82020"
"2.H8","7.61004"
 but the first two lines are actually just from the first line of peaks_ee.xpk and I want to see if the "5.82020" is between a range of 5.1 and 6, and if 7.61004 is between 7 and 8.25. Is there a way I can do this by using the values of the dictionary? I notice that every second line will be the values I want to see if they're between 5.1 and 6, and the alternating values are the ones I want to see if they're between 7 and 8.25.

Edit: This is my complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
import re

i=0;
contents_peak=[]
peak_lines=[]
with open ("ee_pinkH1.xpk","r") as peakPPM:
    for PPM in peakPPM.readlines():
        float_num = re.findall("[\s][1-9]{1}\.[0-9]+",PPM)
        if (len(float_num)>1):
            i=i+1
            value = ('Peak '+ str(i) + ' ' + str(float_num[0]) + ' 0.05 ' + str(float_num[1]) + ' 0.05 ' + '\n')
            peak_lines.insert(-1,value)
tclust_peak = open("tclust.txt","w+")
tclust_peak.write("rbclust \n")
for value in peak_lines:
    tclust_peak.write(value)
tclust_peak.close()

pattern = '''{\d\.H\d'?)}\s(\d\.\d+)\s'''
rex = re.compile(pattern)

j=0;
contents_atom=[]
atom_lines=[]
result = {}
with open("peaks_ee.xpk","r") as atomName:
    for name in atomName:
        for match in rex.finditer(line):
            name,shift = match.groups()
            print (name,shift)
            if name not in result:
                result[name]=float(shift)
                float_str = re.findall("\d\.H\d'?",name)
                if (len(float_str)>1):
                    j=j+1
                    value1 = ('Atom ' +str(j)+ ' ' + str(float_str[0])+ ' ' + str(float_str[1]) + '\n')
                    atom_lines.insert(-1,value)

df = pd.read_csv("D:/tmp/peaks_ee.xpk", sep= " ", skiprows=5)

shift1= df["1H.P"]
shift2= df["1H_2.P"]

mask = ((shift1>5.1) & (shift1<6)) & ((shift2>7) & (shift2<8.25))

result = df[mask]
result = result[["1H.L","1H.P","1H_2.L","1H_2.P"]]
print result

tclust_atom = open("tclust.txt","a")
for value1 in atom_lines:
    tclust_atom.write(value1)
tclust_atom.close()
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd 
  File "/Users/malaikaiyer/Downloads/nmrfxstructure/nmrfxstructure/target/structure-10.1.1-bin/structure-10.1.1/pandas.py", line 23, in <module>
rex = re.compile(pattern)
  File "/Users/malaikaiyer/Downloads/nmrfxstructure/nmrfxstructure/target/structure-10.1.1-bin/structure-10.1.1/lib/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/re.py", line 190, in compile
  File "/Users/malaikaiyer/Downloads/nmrfxstructure/nmrfxstructure/target/structure-10.1.1-bin/structure-10.1.1/lib/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/re.py", line 242, in _compile
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

EDIT: Newest Code 7/26:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
import re
import csv 

i=0;
contents_peak=[]
peak_lines=[]
with open ("ee_pinkH1.xpk","r") as peakPPM:
    for PPM in peakPPM.readlines():
        float_num = re.findall("[\s][1-9]{1}\.[0-9]+",PPM)
        if (len(float_num)>1):
            i=i+1
            value = ('Peak '+ str(i) + ' ' + str(float_num[0]) + ' 0.05 ' + str(float_num[1]) + ' 0.05 ' + '\n')
            peak_lines.insert(-1,value)
tclust_peak = open("tclust.txt","w+")
tclust_peak.write("rbclust \n")
for value in peak_lines:
    tclust_peak.write(value)
tclust_peak.close()

pattern = ‘’’{(\d\.H\d’?)}\s(\d\.\d+)\s'''
rex = re.compile(pattern)

j=0;
contents_atom=[]
atom_lines=[]
result = {}
text = ‘ee’

if text == ‘ee’:
    df = pd.read_csv('peaks_ee.xpk', sep=" ",skiprows=5)

    shift1= df["1H.P"]
    shift= df["1H_2.P"]
    if filename == 'ee_pinkH1.xpk'
        mask = ((shift1>5.1) & (shift1<6)) & ((shift2>7) & (shift2<8.25))
    elif filename == 'ee_pinkH2.xpk'
        mask = ((shift1>3.25)&(shift1<5))&((shift2>7)&(shift2<8.5))
    result = df[mask]
    result = result[["1H.L","1H.P","1H_2.L","1H_2.P"]]
    result.to_csv("result.csv")

if text == ‘ef’:
    df = pd.read_csv('peaks_ef.xpk', sep=" ",skiprows=5)

    shift1= df["1H.P"]
    shift2= df["1H_2.P"]
    if filename == ‘ef_blue.xpk’:
        mask = ((shift1>5) & (shift1<6)) & ((shift2>7.25) & (shift2<8.25))
    elif filename == ‘ef_green.xpk’:
        mask = ((shift1>7) & (shift1<9)) & ((shift2>5.25) & (shift2<6.2))
    elif filename == ‘ef_orange:
        mask = ((shift1>3) & (shift1<5)) & ((shift2>5.2) & (shift2<6.25))
    result = df[mask]
    result = result[["1H.L","1H.P","1H_2.L","1H_2.P"]]
    result.to_csv("result.csv")

if text == ‘fe’:
    df = pd.read_csv('peaks_fe.xpk', sep=" ",skiprows=5)

    shift1= df[“Atom1”]
    shift2= df[“Atom2”]
    if filename == ‘fe_yellow’:
        mask = ((shift1>3) & (shift1<5)) & ((shift2>5) & (shift2<6))
    elif filename == ‘fe_green’:
        mask = ((shift1>5.1) & (shift1<6)) & ((shift2>7) & (shift2<8.25))
        result = df[mask]
        result = result[["1H.L","1H.P","1H_2.L","1H_2.P"]]
        result.to_csv("result.csv")

tclust_peak = open("tclust.txt”,”a")
tclust_peak.write((str(result))
tclust_atom.close()
```

Comment: Your text file scares me.

Comment: Honestly, the Python scares me, too. So much nesting. I feel like there must be a better way to do that.

Comment: You're probably better off using a `pandas.DataFrame`. There you have easy access to the single columns and can easily apply conditions to them.

Comment: Your indentation is not valid.

Comment: Yes,I'm pretty sure that the nesting is not good but I'm not sure how else to do it @CoryMadden

Comment: I've never used pandas.DataFrame, would that let me get values from my text file and compare them to actual numbers?

Comment: Let me rephrase: You have an extra indentation after `print` that means this will not run: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: @user8358234 I'd start by writing some functions. I agree that `pandas` would be the best way to go with this data. Yes, you can load data from a text file.

Comment: @CoryMadden but in the text file, everything is read as a character right? so then how can I compare it to an actual number? is that a function of using pandas?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if the output is what you expected.

Comment: @user8358234 Yes, `pandas` is especially good for reading large textfiles of data and converting it to usable data such as numbers and dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package.

Following code would load your file and skip the first five rows in order to load the data you want. Then it does bitwise check between the columns for creating the mask, and finally selects the columns you want.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("peaks_ee.xpk", sep=" ", skiprows=5)

shift1 = df["1H.P"]
shift2 = df["1H_2.P"]

mask = ((shift1>5.1) & (shift1<6)) & ((shift2>7) & (shift2<8.25))

result = df[mask]
result = result[["1H.L","1H.P","1H_2.L","1H_2.P"]]
```

Result would be as follows:

```
>>> result
       1H.L     1H.P  1H_2.L   1H_2.P
0   {1.H1'}  5.82020  {2.H8}  7.61004
3   {1.H1'}  5.82020  {1.H8}  8.13712
5   {2.H1'}  5.90291  {2.H8}  7.61004
8   {1.H1'}  5.82020  {2.H8}  7.61004
11  {4.H1'}  5.74125  {3.H6}  7.53261
12  {3.H1'}  5.54935  {4.H8}  7.49932
15  {3.H1'}  5.54935  {3.H6}  7.53261
18  {2.H1'}  5.90291  {3.H6}  7.53261
21  {4.H1'}  5.74125  {4.H8}  7.49932
24  {3.H1'}  5.54935  {4.H8}  7.49932
```

Then if you want you can export the `result` to a csv file as follows:

```
result.to_csv("result.csv")
```

I am not sure if this code is exactly what you need, but it may be a good start for you on how to use `pandas`.

Comment: hey thank you for helping me! I'm not able to run the code, I'll edit my question so you can see the errors I'm getting and a picture of my code.

Comment: Did you try just the code I provided? Is the output of result what you expected?

Comment: Hi, I tried the code you provided. I wrote it as an edit in my question and showed what the error I get is

Comment: I realized I had certain problems with my code but now everything inside the code seems to be syntactically correct. But now my only error is: 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_csv'

Comment: Can you update the code you ran? I'm still wondering if the output I stated on my answer us what you expect.

Comment: I updated my question with my newest code at the very bottom

Comment: and yes the output is what I expected but I don't need the "1H.L","1H.P","1H_2.L","1H_2.P", and I didn't want the chemical shifts actually printed out, I just wanted the atom names printed out

Comment: You may be getting errors due to the quotes. Try replacing ’ by ' and ‘ by ' as well.

Comment: Also be careful about characters “ and ”, they should be " instead.

Comment: Also I suggest you try only the code I put in my answer and check you get no errors. Hope you find it useful ;)

Comment: thank you very much, your code worked. One question, if I wanted to write out the result to an already existing txt file called "tclust.txt" could I do:
`tclust_peak=open("tclust.txt","a")

 tclust_peak.write((str(result))

 tclust_atom.close()`

Comment: Regarding your code, I have kind of a separate question, should I create a new question for it? My question is basically, in the output of the code you wrote, I only want to write out the atom names. For example I want to print "1.H1'" and "2.H8" from the first line without the braces. And how can I not have the `1H.L     1H.P  1H_2.L   1H_2.P` line appear in the output?